# time of executing queries in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, linux, bash, postgresql

I'm trying to write a script which show me the time of executing some queries I have 2 problems with my script:
1. Why the result of function is 0?
2. How to make that /copy will not overwrite my file(test.txt)?

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

psql WYPOZYCZALNIA postgres<< EOF

    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION funkcja(i integer) returns double precision as'
            DECLARE
            czas_start double precision;
            czas_stop double precision;
            BEGIN
            SELECT extract(epoch from now()) into czas_start;
            insert into UZYTKOWNICY VALUES(16,''PIOTiR'',''510784543'');
            SELECT extract(epoch from now()) into czas_stop;
            RETURN czas_stop-czas_start;
    end;
    'language 'plpgsql';
    \copy   (select * from funkcja(50)) To 'test.txt'
    \q
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `NOW()` is a alias for and transaction_timestamp(), and returns always *the start time of the current transaction*, therefore returns always the same value inside a stored procedure. See [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html) for more details:

> statement_timestamp() and transaction_timestamp() return the same
>   value during the first command of a transaction,

To fix you issue, use `timeofday()` or `clock_timestamp()` instead of `NOW()`:

> timeofday() is a historical PostgreSQL function. Like
>   clock_timestamp(), it returns the actual current time, but as a
>   formatted text string rather than a timestamp with time zone value.

To use it whit EXTRACT(), cast the result to TIMESTAMP with `timeofday()::TIMESTAMP`:

```
SELECT extract(epoch from timeofday()::TIMESTAMP) into czas_start;
insert into UZYTKOWNICY VALUES(16,''PIOTiR'',''510784543'');
SELECT extract(epoch from timeofday()::TIMESTAMP) into czas_stop;
```

**How to append the result instead of overwrite the output file**

The `\copy` command does not support append instead of overwrite, so better you don't use `\copy` but run the function in psql and redirect the output to the file:

```
#!/bin/bash

psql WYPOZYCZALNIA postgres<< EOF

    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION funkcja(i integer) returns double precision as \$BODY$
            DECLARE
            czas_start double precision;
            czas_stop double precision;
            BEGIN
            SELECT extract(epoch from timeofday()::TIMESTAMP) into czas_start;
            INSERT INTO UZYTKOWNICY  VALUES(16,'PIOTiR','510784543');
            SELECT extract(epoch from timeofday()::TIMESTAMP) into czas_stop;
            RETURN czas_stop-czas_start;
    end;
    \$BODY$ language 'plpgsql';
EOF
psql WYPOZYCZALNIA postgres -t -A -c "SELECT funkcja(50)" >> 'test.txt'
```

The psql option `-A` means do not align the output and `-t` means show only tuple in output.

**Considerations**

- The function accept a argument but than does not use it. Eventually remove the parameter.
- Loading the function every time you want to run it is a bad design. Better you separate the function definition from running it in two different files. The function should loaded only once, by database setup.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer.

Comment: How to make that ( \copy   (select * from funkcja(50)) To 'test.txt')  will not overwrite test.txt? I would like to have  all results in 1 file.